# Difference between # and > in paperclip styles for image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have seen that in using `:styles` attributes in Paperclip, you ca specify sizes with **#**, as `:thumb => "100x100#"` as well as with **>**, as `:medium => "480x320>"`. I am not exactly sure about the difference between the usage of # and >. Can anyone please enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These follow the rules of formatting for ImageMagick which can be [found here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php?ImageMagick=lj6pre8q2iautc3ch6nuph1fc2#geometry)
The `>` lets the image keep the same aspect ratio when it is being scaled so it doesn't get distorted.

You will not find the `#` key in the ImageMagick docs though, that is special to paperclip. It allows simple cropping of thumbnails to the specified size. [See here for a good explanation](http://web.archive.org/web/20110810233911/http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html) [via Wayback Machine], about halfway down the page.

Comment: The linked page no longer lists the explanation, but one can be found in the documentation of the "has_attached_file" method: _"Paperclip also adds the “#” option (e.g. “50x50#”), which will resize the image to fit maximally inside the dimensions and then crop the rest off (weighted at the center)._

Comment: Thank goodness for the Wayback Machine. I updated the link to the archive from around the time that this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

The string you are referring to is passed to ImageMagick as a geometry string.  You can read more about the possible values here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html

Comment: The geometry docs don't say anything about the modifiers, you want to look at the [resize docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/). And the `#` modifier is not part of ImageMagick proper.

Comment: Yes it does.. it explains the !%>< modifiers.  The '#' modifier is specific however to paperclip.

Comment: Right, doing a quick search for the one thing (`#`) that isn't part of ImageMagick usually doesn't work. But the [paperclip docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation) do explain the `#` modifier and point you at docs for the ImageMagick ones.